# CoreBluetooth Crashes with fast updating characteristic

Tags: c++, ios, uiviewcontroller, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a very fast updating BLE Characteristic (>20 updates per second). My app works fine up to the point where I begin to receive updates from the characteristic. The characteristic is set to notify.

My app as two ViewControllers, one to select and connect BLE devices the other to read characteristics and subscribe to them. The crash occurs when moving away back to the View Controller which discovers the BLE devices.

(lldb) bt reports the following:-

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1605b9, 0x000000019700bbd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend +    16, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
  * frame #0: 0x000000019700bbd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16
    frame #1: 0x0000000185440b3c CoreBluetooth`-[CBPeripheral handleMsg:args:] + 284
    frame #2: 0x000000018543c9d4 CoreBluetooth`-[CBCentralManager xpcConnection:didReceiveMsg:args:] + 164
    frame #3: 0x0000000100138fd4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    frame #4: 0x0000000100138f94 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #5: 0x0000000100143db8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 780
    frame #6: 0x000000010013c2c4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
    frame #7: 0x000000010013d6f4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 532
    frame #8: 0x000000018578b7f8 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    frame #9: 0x00000001857898a0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1492
    frame #10: 0x00000001856b52d4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    frame #11: 0x000000018eecb6fc GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
    frame #12: 0x000000018a27afac UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
    frame #13: 0x00000001000d861c Sting Ray Controller (v3) i5 1.0.2`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd2f9e0) + 124 at main.m:14
    frame #14: 0x0000000197676a08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

I'm only guessing but is this because its trying to read and process the characteristic as I close the ViewController running collecting the updates?

Comment: It looks like you have a CBCentralManager that is holding a reference to an deal located object. Make sure you clear your CBCentral delegate when the VC is dismissed and perhaps try enabling zombies.

Comment: Hi, I've released the characteristics which were notifying on moving away from the ViewController:

eg

        [_DetailmymPeripheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:self.SRBatteryCBCharacteristic];

This appears to have stabalised (a bit)...may try enabling Zombies too...